# Failed to send message back on synchronous queue (Timer already cancelled)

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

We are using a single broker ActiveMQ (5.10.2). After having some problems caused by slow consumers, we had to restart ActiveMQ.

Since we restarted it, we have these warning logs on the broker side :

```
2020-06-12 10:40:20,232 | WARN  | Failed to register MBean org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=customer-prod,destinationType=Queue,destinationName=PROD.CORE.GET.Q.REPLY | org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagedRegionBroker | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///ip:53068@61616
```

Regularly, we send messages synchronously on the queue **PROD.CORE.GET** and the JMS consumer (connected through **HTTP**) sends the response back on the queue **PROD.CORE.GET.Q.REPLY**.

As soon as the JMS consumer responds, we get this following error and the response is never sent to the broker :

```
2020-06-12 08:29:54,802 [WARN ]  [] - Execution of JMS message listener failed. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException - org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Timer already cancelled.]
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Timer already cancelled.
        at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1826) ~[camel-core-2.24.1.jar:2.24.1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:134) ~[camel-jms-2.24.1.jar:2.24.1]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:736) ~[spring-jms-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:696) ~[spring-jms-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:674) ~[spring-jms-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:318) [spring-jms-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:257) [spring-jms-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1190) [spring-jms-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1180) [spring-jms-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1077) [spring-jms-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
Caused by: org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Timer already cancelled.
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:311) ~[spring-jms-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:185) ~[spring-jms-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:507) ~[spring-jms-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.send(JmsConfiguration.java:556) ~[camel-jms-2.24.1.jar:2.24.1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.sendReply(EndpointMessageListener.java:370) ~[camel-jms-2.24.1.jar:2.24.1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener$EndpointMessageListenerAsyncCallback.done(EndpointMessageListener.java:223) ~[camel-jms-2.24.1.jar:2.24.1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:117) ~[camel-jms-2.24.1.jar:2.24.1]
        ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Timer already cancelled.
        at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:54) ~[activemq-client-5.15.10.jar:5.15.10]
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1403) ~[activemq-client-5.15.10.jar:5.15.10]
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.send(ActiveMQSession.java:1972) ~[activemq-client-5.15.10.jar:5.15.10]
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducer.send(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:288) ~[activemq-client-5.15.10.jar:5.15.10]
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducer.send(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:223) ~[activemq-client-5.15.10.jar:5.15.10]
        at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledProducer.send(PooledProducer.java:95) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.15.10.jar:5.15.10]
        at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledProducer.send(PooledProducer.java:66) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.15.10.jar:5.15.10]
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doSend(JmsTemplate.java:634) ~[spring-jms-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.doSend(JmsConfiguration.java:634) ~[camel-jms-2.24.1.jar:2.24.1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.doSendToDestination(JmsConfiguration.java:573) ~[camel-jms-2.24.1.jar:2.24.1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.access$100(JmsConfiguration.java:515) ~[camel-jms-2.24.1.jar:2.24.1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate$4.doInJms(JmsConfiguration.java:558) ~[camel-jms-2.24.1.jar:2.24.1]
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:504) ~[spring-jms-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
        ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer already cancelled.
        at java.util.Timer.sched(Timer.java:397) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.Timer.schedule(Timer.java:248) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at org.apache.activemq.thread.Scheduler.executePeriodically(Scheduler.java:41) ~[activemq-client-5.15.10.jar:5.15.10]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue.start(Queue.java:1039) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.AbstractRegion.addDestination(AbstractRegion.java:141) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.RegionBroker.addDestination(RegionBroker.java:334) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addDestination(BrokerFilter.java:172) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addDestination(BrokerFilter.java:172) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.MutableBrokerFilter.addDestination(MutableBrokerFilter.java:177) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addDestination(BrokerFilter.java:172) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.MutableBrokerFilter.addDestination(MutableBrokerFilter.java:177) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.RegionBroker.send(RegionBroker.java:448) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagedRegionBroker.send(ManagedRegionBroker.java:297) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.CompositeDestinationBroker.send(CompositeDestinationBroker.java:96) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransactionBroker.send(TransactionBroker.java:307) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.MutableBrokerFilter.send(MutableBrokerFilter.java:157) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.util.TimeStampingBrokerPlugin.send(TimeStampingBrokerPlugin.java:131) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.send(BrokerFilter.java:152) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.MutableBrokerFilter.send(MutableBrokerFilter.java:157) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processMessage(TransportConnection.java:541) ~[na:na]
```

Since it was an emergency to solve the problem, we tried to restart ActiveMQ again and the problem seems to be solved (all previous warn and error logs disappeared immediately).

We would like to know what happened but I cannot find any relevant answer on the web. That's why I am asking for help ! :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That version is extremely old so any bugs you happen to find aren't going to get fixed in a point release, you should really move up to the latest release.

Comment: @TimBish Thanks for your quick answer. Upgrading to 5.15.x is in the pipeline but for this emergency I would have liked to understand what caused this problem.